# Parser Error for RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

and this is the page code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
            Choose a Foreground (Text) Color:<br/>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="lstForeColor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LstForeColor_OnSelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            <br/><br/>
            Choose a Background Color:<br/>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="lstBackColor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstBackColor_OnSelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
            Choose a Border Style:<br/>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="lstBorder" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstBorder_OnSelectedIndexChanged" RepeatColumns="2"/>
            <br/>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPictre" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkPictre_OnCheckedChanged" Text="Add Deafult Picture"/>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
            Choose a fint name:<br/>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="lstFontName" runat="server"AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="lstFontName_OnTextChanged"/>
            <br/><br/>
            Enter the greeting text Below:<br/>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtGreeting" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtGreeting_OnTextChanged" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
</div>
</form>
```

I tried to change ID, removes some properties, add closing tags, but none of them worked, I'm wondering why I'm getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between properties in `lstFontName`. Change

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lstFontName" runat="server"AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="lstFontName_OnTextChanged"/>
```

into

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lstFontName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="lstFontName_OnTextChanged"/>
```

There must be a space between `runat="server"` and `AutoPostBack="True"`

Comment: Thanks.that worked, the error message  was referring to the wrong line.still some people say compiler never make mistakes.